# Screen Flickering while decreasing brightness

Tags: screen, 18.10

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 in Samsung Notebook NP600B4C-A10US. Problem is when i try to decrease the brightness below 75%, it start to flicker.

Same happened in Ubuntu 18.04